# MATLAB plot of 2 variables defined by an equation

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I have the following query. I want to plot in MATLAB the following equation :

`i + s - ln(s)/sigma = constant`  (`i` and `s` are variables)

for a given value of `constant` and `sigma`. The equation is between `s` and `i`. the value of `sigma` is 0.5 and value of `constant` can be assumed to be 1.

I want to plot the above equation. `i` and `s` both are function of time but in graph we need graph of `s` & `i` only. `i` on y axis and `s` on x axis.

Comment: You have mentioned that `s` and `i` are a function of another parameter (time). Do you know the values of `s` and `i` directly in this example though? If so, can simply `plot(s,i)` be a solution to you?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: no i don't know the value of s and i for this particular equation since  they are changing with time

Comment: @halfer sorry for such word usage i agree

Answer (score 1):

try `fimplicit`

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit.html

```
f=@(s,i) i + s - log(s)/2 - 5;
fimplicit(f,[1 5 2 10])
```

Comment: is [1 5 2 10] the time interval ??

Comment: I tried to plot but I can see nothing on the plot

Comment: just read the help link - it explains everything you need to know about this function, pretty simple and won't take too much of your time.